# Django how to change a vallue of a field that received error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Thanks for your time.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to set a object from a database list (.csv) and if i get an ValueError I would like to set that field value and keep adding data

> ValueError: Field 'age' expected a number but got 'M'

I'm quite sure that's a doc for this, but I've been reading for some time and hasn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about filtering the data once you receive it? For example lets say age field expects an Integer, and before you save it you could check if the data is an Integer. But I also think the most efficient way is using try except.

Comment: yeah, rewrite the .save() method on models. Don't know why havn't thought that

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple 'try', 'except' block should work where you have a default value to use in 'except' before saving.

Comment: i'm searching for something more precise to find the field that got error and sent a common value that would work for any field  that receives a ValueError.